# Website theme color not changing

Tags: jquery, css, html, web

I want change website theme color and i'm using this way its not working properly. Can anyone help?

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="switch" class="gray-color">&nbsp;</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="switch2" class="green-color">&nbsp;</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="switch3" class="yellow-color">&nbsp;</a>

$("#switch").click(function () {
               $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme-gray.css"  title="gray" class="gray" />');
               $('link[title="yellow"]').remove();               
           });
$("#switch3").click(function () {
               $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme-yellow.css"  title="yellow" class="yellow" />');
               $('link[title="gray"]').remove();   
           });
$("#switch2").click(function () {
               $('link[title="yellow"]').remove();
               $('link[title="gray"]').remove();
 });
```

Refer the screens

Comment: do you want to change color to link or append new and then delete the new???

Comment: I want change color to link but i used append method

Comment: What do you mean by "not working properly"? What happens?

Comment: Two color only changing. third color not changing

Comment: Reference screen image link one:https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OfSBa9K3a6sKn9mXeZ2I5yHr1HY41SgF,

Comment: Reference screen image link two: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_-Kufy49kybtuf0h3OaU9T4KgNwCclC4

Answer (score 2):

Try out this code.

```js
$(".theme-link").click(function () {
    console.log($(this).attr("data-theme"));

    $('#theme').attr("href", $(this).attr("data-theme") );        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" id="theme" href="css/theme-gray.css"  title="gray" class="gray" />

<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-theme="css/theme-gray.css" class="theme-link">gary</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-theme="css/theme-green.css" class="theme-link">green</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-theme="css/theme-yellow.css" class="theme-link">yellow</a>
```